# Yii 2.0: Overriding Bootstrap CSS causes glyphicons fail

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, yii2, glyphicons

I'm trying to override Bootstrap css in my project. 
Adding this code to config file works, but then all glyphicons not displayed correctly

```
'assetManager' => [
'bundles' => [
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
         'sourcePath' => '@webroot',
         'css' => ['css/bootstrap.css']
         ],
    ],
],
```

Page before:
[image]

Page after:
[image]

I understand that font files is missing but how to add them?

Comment: if your problem is only missing glyphicon file, why dont u try and export the glyphicon component on bootstrap and add it to ur file. hopefully it would override the existing one if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, bootstrap.css expects the fonts to be located in a fonts folder that is a sibling of the css folder. This folder does not exist in your implementation.

From the docs for `$sourcePath` for [`yii\web\Asset`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetbundle.html):

> You must set this property if the directory containing the source asset files is not Web accessible. By setting this property, `yii\web\AssetManager` will publish the source asset files to a Web-accessible directory automatically when the asset bundle is registered on a page.

The default `$sourcePath` for `yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset` is set to `@bower/bootstrap/dist`. This folder contains a 3 subfolders: `css`, `js` and `fonts`, which are all published into the `assets` folder.

To fix this you need to either:

1. Copy the fonts and js folders from `vendor/bower/bootstrap/dist` into your webroot to maintain the link.
2. Change the `$sourcePath` to a copy of the `bootstrap/dist` folder and replace the bootstrap.css in it with your own copy.

You could also change the path to fonts directly in your bootstrap.css but I wouldn't recommend it as it is harder to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

So it was my misunderstanding of yii2 & bootstrap.
To override bootstrap css we need to copy bootstrap distributive (not only bootstap.css) to new directory, in my case it was Web accessible web/custombootstrap/dist

And override in config file as following:

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
            'basePath' => '@webroot',
            'baseUrl' => '@web/custombootstrap/dist',
            'css' => ['css/bootstrap.css']
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 4 minutes.